# Automatically switching dimension in array indexing (python)

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I want to automatize the following operation in Python. Given a n-dimensional `np.array`, e.g.

```
ar = np.array([[[ 8, 10],
                [ 9, 11],
                [10, 12]],
               [[ 9, 11],
                [10, 12],
                [11, 13]]])
```

With names for each of the dimensions in `dim_names`, e.g.

```
dim_names = ['A','B','C']
```

select all the marginals of any given dimension, e.g.

```
ind  = dim_names.index('B')

for i in range(ar.shape[ind]):
    print(ar[:,i,:])
```

But depending on `ind` the indexing has to change, e.g. for `ind = 0` we need `ar[i,:,:]` or for `ind = 2` `ar[:,:,i]`. Furthermore it should work for an array of any number of dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a better approach for your problem, but as for the question, you can construct the index dynamically in the *loop*, i.e. specify the desired dimension of the index and slice.

Slice along first dimension:

```
ind = 0
​
for i in range(ar.shape[ind]):
    idx = [slice(None)] * ar.ndim             # inintialize the index with the same length 
                                              # as the dimensions
    idx[ind] = i                              # modify the index of the desired dimension
    print(ar[tuple(idx)])

#[[ 8 10]
# [ 9 11]
# [10 12]]
#[[ 9 11]
# [10 12]
# [11 13]]
```

Slice along second dimension:

```
ind = 1
​
for i in range(ar.shape[ind]):
    idx = [slice(None)] * ar.ndim
    idx[ind] = i
    print(ar[tuple(idx)])

#[[ 8 10]
# [ 9 11]]
#[[ 9 11]
# [10 12]]
#[[10 12]
# [11 13]]
```

Slice along third dimension:

```
ind = 2
​
for i in range(ar.shape[ind]):
    idx = [slice(None)] * ar.ndim
    idx[ind] = i
    print(ar[tuple(idx)])

#[[ 8  9 10]
# [ 9 10 11]]
#[[10 11 12]
# [11 12 13]]
```